# Third Camera in the Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a game but one problem bothers me, is I want the camera to follow the player, or I want to create a Third Camera, but the camera starts to twitch constantly, the control is not convenient. Unity version 2018.4.16f1 Personal

Do not beat me, I only study unity :D

.[Image in the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PXQk.png)

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials on cameras, make your own if you dont like how it currently works, change it

Comment: The fact of the matter is that in the first and second tutorials everything constantly twitched and did not work, although it did everything as they did, in the third, fourth and fifth my camera teleported to the void, I tried even one of the assets, but it still doesn’t work. (Google Translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its really simple:

put this script on the camera and put the player into the myPlayer variable.

```
public Vector3 myPosition;
public Transform myPlayer;

public void Update()
{
   transform.position = myPlayer.position + myPosition;
}
```